# LinkedIn fills data in my application in Portuguese

Tags: linkedin

When I'm sending a job application through LinkedIn, it populates both the work experience and education in Portuguese, as the next image shows

[image]

Since the applications are in English, I end up removing everything from there but not only that is bothersome work but also can mean that the profile gets excluded right way.

How to proceed to have that in English?

---

Note that I have the Site preferences set to English for both language

[image]

and content language

[image]

and that in the profile default doesn't change to English

[image]